# Modify .msg files and save it PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need to modify my .msg template and save it.
i try:

```
$file= <file location>
$outlook= New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
$msg= $outlook.createitemfromtemplate($file)
$msg.body= $msg.body -replace "Name", "Mark"
$msg.save()
```

But my template have picture in body message and pictures are lost. How i can save it ?

Comment: You mean as a draft?

Comment: actualy, i need to send it after

Answer (score 0):

Editing `$msg.HTMLbody` instead of `$msg.Body` worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).